# how to alert @Html.EditorFor value which has integer data type in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

i have given data type int to ID in model ,now when i call javascript to alert it ,it doesn't display any result instead it display [object object].i want to display value of that ID.
any tips on that would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try this:

$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            success: function (result) {
                $('#elementid').html(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});

$('#elementid').html(result)
```

gives you value instead of  [object object].